# Doubt on Documentation rule for creating app

Tags: apps, release-odin

I planned to create an app using elementary guideline and to publish it. My plan revolved around an app like KDE connect which is really awesome. I planned to use may be FTP or bluetooth or nextcloud like any service for syncing some files of other developer app. I planned to create android app so that the data can be modified from phone which can be synced to the directories where that database is saved. But my plan about that is stuck at some point because of ONE of the rule given in documentation.
Rule Says :

" Your app must not attempt to modify, replace, or append software sources on the target system.
Your app must not attempt to modify other apps or system programs."
[image]

But my idea exactly does opposite of these statements.

0. Don't you think the documentation statement is a barrier for developer even if its open source app ?
1. What does software sources means , which should not be modified ? (contextual sense I dont know)
2. Does the first line refer to software sources in  locations like /* , /var , /boot , / etc not like /var/log or /home/$USER/.config etc ?
3. What exactly modify means on second sentence ? ( Why i am asking because ..... is it about modifying user data or app setting data,,,,, both are different as one is in .config one might be in .local)
4. Is it okey if I can add Privacy policy or concent that my app can access some of your personal data u want to sync ?
5. Is it possible to ask other developers ... if i can use their app database and sync ,modify it ?

> ```
>  if (they say yes || no):
>           above rule still stopping me
> ```

Any clarification around it would be really helpful.
** My Experience includes android app development (strong rules though for accessing data), bit of web development and Byte of UX development sense.*

Comment: Software sources means apt repositories, flatpak remotes, snap channels etc. The only applications which should modify these are those applications which were created specifically for the management of one's software sources. No other app should touch these. To be honest, I don't think you need to touch these with your app either.

Comment: @m93a is it okey if my app changes files in home folder or other app storage

Comment: It definitely *is* okay, or at least not in contradiction with the rule you ask about, as long as you keep stuff like `~/snap` intact. User data are neither _"other apps or system programs"_, nor they are _"software sources"_.